# yum - No package httpd available (new VPS)

Tags: linux, yum, apache-httpd, vps

So I have a new VPS that only has the bare bones.  Not what I was expecting at all and I may be well past my depth but I'm trying to get the essentials running.  The host is Swedish and aggressively unhelpful.

`uname -a` output:

> Linux myhostname.com 2.6.32-431.el6.i686 #1 SMP Fri Nov 22 00:26:36 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

So I was trying to locate and start Apache.  `apachectl start` is unknown.  `lsof -nPi | grep ":80 (LISTEN)"` has no output.  There's no reference to `httpd` or `apache2` in `/etc/init.d/`.

So I started by trying to install Apache like so:

```
$ yum install httpd
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.sunet.se
 * extras: ftp.sunet.se
 * updates: ftp.sunet.se
Setting up Install Process
No package httpd available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

`rpm -qa | grep httpd` has no output so I checked `/etc/yum.conf` and I see `httpd` in exclude line:

```
exclude=bind-chroot courier* dovecot* exim* filesystem httpd* mod_ssl* mydns* mysql* nsd* php* proftpd* pure-ftpd* ruby* spamassassin* squirrelmail*
```

I'm stuck as to what to do.  I'm pretty sure Apache is not present and PHP as well.  MySQL is running fine.

#### Questions

- Since the host is ignoring my emails what would be the harm in removing `httpd` from the ignore list?
- Also if `yum.conf` has no repositories listed do I need to add them?

Answer (score 9):

I would remove `httpd*` from that exclude list in `yum.conf` for starters. Also each repo is typically not listed in `yum.conf` but rather in the directory `/etc/yum.repo.d`, typically. There's often this comment at the end of that file:

```
# PUT YOUR REPOS HERE OR IN separate files named file.repo
# in /etc/yum.repos.d
```

#### Example

```
$ ls /etc/yum.repos.d/
fedora.repo                             home:pstavirs:ostinato.repo             rpmfusion-free-updates.repo             rpmfusion-nonfree-updates.repo
fedora-updates.repo                     home:tpokorra:mono.repo                 rpmfusion-free-updates-testing.repo     rpmfusion-nonfree-updates-testing.repo
fedora-updates-testing.repo             rpmfusion-free-rawhide.repo             rpmfusion-nonfree-rawhide.repo          rpm-sphere.repo
google-chrome.repo                      rpmfusion-free.repo                     rpmfusion-nonfree.repo                  virtualbox.repo
```

Rather than edit the `yum.conf` you can run `yum` one off and tell it to override the excludes like so, `--disableexcludes=[all|main|repoid]`.

```
   --disableexcludes=[all|main|repoid]
        Disable the excludes defined in your config files. Takes one of 
        three options:
          all == disable all excludes
          main == disable excludes defined in [main] in yum.conf
          repoid == disable excludes defined for that repo
```

#### Example

```
$ sudo yum --disableexcludes=all install httpd
```

Comment: You make my day thank u